# Inheritance with packages/namespaces [C#]

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces, package

I want to redefine the classes of a package in a sub-package while keeping the hierarchy.

I would have wanted to do something like this :

```
namespace RPG {

  public class Actor {}

  public class Character : Actor {}
}

public class Actor : RPG.Actor {}

//kind of a diamond problem
public class Character : Actor, RPG.Character {}
```

I know this is incorrect ; C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, but I don't know the best way to resolve this kind of redefinition.

Interfaces doesn't solve my problem. I could do something like that using composition :

```
public class Character : Actor {

    private RPG.Character basis;

    // and do this for each attribute and method
    public int atk { get { return basis.atk } set { basis.atk = value; } }
}
```

but it doesn't look good. Moreover, I ran into another problem with this way

```
namespace RPG {

    public class Actor {

        public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stat {}
}

public class Actor {

    private RPG.Actor basis;

    //I can't do that because Stat does not inherit from RPG.Stat
    public override List<RPG.Stat> stats { get; set; }
}

public class Stat {

    private RPG.Stat basis;
}
```

What is the best way to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [composition](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80045/Composition-VS-Inheritance) instead of inheritance.

It's tough to draw a direct example because you didn't provide any actions for your RPG actor/characters but the concept is that you inject the behaviors in the constructor of your class.

In this case "move" is the behavior:

```
class Fighter
{
    public int Health = 100;
    public string Name;

    private Move _move;

    public string MoveName
    {
        get
        {
            return _move.Name;
        }
    }
    public int MoveDamage
    {
        get
        {
            return _move.Damage;
        }
    }

    public Fighter(string name, Move defaultMove)
    {
        Name = name;

        _move = defaultMove;
    }

    public void Attack(Fighter defendant)
    {
        if (_move != null)
            _move.Attack(defendant);
    }

    public void SetMove(Move move)
    {
        if (move != null)
            _move = move;
    }
}

abstract class Move
{
    public int Damage { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    protected Move(int damage,string name)
    {
        Damage = damage;
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Attack(Fighter defendant)
    {
        defendant.Health -= Damage;
    }
}

class PunchMove:Move
{
    public PunchMove() : base(5, "Punch")
    {
    }
}

class KickMove:Move
{
    public KickMove() : base(7, "Kick")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
namespace RPG {

  public class Actor {

  public void d(){
  System.Console.Write("fhdf");
  }

  }

  public class Character : Actor {}
}


////////////////
public class Character :  RPG.Character {}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Character c = new Character();
        c.d();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this do? How does this answer the question?

Comment: it is inheritance hierarchy. Inheriting from child class can access all public members of all its parents in the tree.(e.g. A is parent B is child in namespace Z and D is child to B in another namespace then B can access A's public members.